# Dynamic template resolver using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, template-engine

We have a requirement to dynamically resolve html or text templates. The template content (a string) with variable place holders will be available in database.

We have to resolve them dynamically on demand with the actual values for the variables and get the final string content.

*Example: (not a complete code)*

```
String myHtmlTemplateContent = "<h1>Hi ${first_name} ${last_name}</h1>";
Map<String, Object> myMapWithValues = ..;
engine.resolve(myHtmlTemplateContent , myMapWithValues );
```

Will be helpful if we have a way to resolve using thymeleaf or is it possible using thymeleaf template engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a thymeleaf template `mytemplate.html` containing:

```
<h1 th:text="Hi ${first_name} ${last_name}"></h1>
```

and use it with a mvc controller that sets the variables in the model:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String handle(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("first_name", "Abel");
        model.addAttribute("last_name", "Lincon");
        return "mytemplate"; //resolves to mytemplate.html
    }
}
```

And it will render `<h1>Hi Abel Lincon</h1>`

If you want to manually process a template, you could autowire the template engine and use it manually:

```
@Autowired SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

String emailContent = templateEngine.process( "mytemplate",
                        new Context( Locale.ENGLISH, Map.of(
                                "first_name", "Abel",
                                "last_name", "Lincon"
                        )) );
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve without a HTML file -  meaning with a string as mentioned in question.

Comment: @mperle why are you trying to do this with a string? The main usage is with html files that have the advantage they can be displayed in browser (thymeleaf templates are valid htmls)

Comment: Correct. The scenario is we need to process the html string and send the processed string as email body.

Comment: cdalxndr, that helps the i was scenario looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following approach:

```java
import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.context.Context;
import java.util.Map;

public class GenericTemplateEngine {

    private final TemplateEngine templateEngine;

    public GenericTemplateEngine(TemplateMode templateMode) {

        templateEngine = new org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine();

        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver
                = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver(Thread
                        .currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(templateMode);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/thymeleaf/");
        templateResolver.setCacheTTLMs(3600000L); // one hour
        templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
        this.templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
    }

    public String getTemplate(String templateName, Map<String, Object> parameters) {
        Context ctx = new Context();
        if (parameters != null) {
            parameters.forEach((k, v) -> {
                ctx.setVariable(k, v);
            });
        }
        return this.templateEngine.process(templateName, ctx).trim();
    }

}
```

This can then be called as follows for HTML templates:

```
HashMap<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("hello", "hello everyone");
GenericTemplateEngine engine = new GenericTemplateEngine(TemplateMode.HTML);
String s = engine.getTemplate("hello_world.html", values);
System.out.println(s);
```

The values in the Map are loaded into the Thymeleaf context, and then passed, along with a template, to the engine class.

If you have a text template instead of an HTML template, then you would use the following:

```
new GenericTemplateEngine(TemplateMode.TEXT);
```